# why do I get: "unsupervised_wiener() got an unexpected keyword argument 'max_num_iter'" when using skimage.restoration.unsupervised_wiener?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-image, deconvolution, wiener-filter

i am playing around with scikit image restoration package and successfully ran the unsupervised_wiener algorithm on some made up data. In this simple example it does what I expect, but on my more complicated dataset it returns a striped pattern with extreme values of -1 and 1.

I would like to fiddle with the parameters to better understand what is going on, but I get the error as stated in the question. I tried scikit image version 0.19.3 and downgraded to scikit image version 0.19.2, but the error remains.

The same goes for the "other parameters":https://scikit-image.org/docs/0.19.x/api/skimage.restoration.html#skimage.restoration.unsupervised_wiener

Can someone explain why I can't input parameters?

The example below contains a "scan" and a "point-spread-function". I convolve the scan with the point spread function and then reverse the process using the unsupervised wiener deconvolution.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage import color, data, restoration
import pickle

rng = np.random.default_rng()

from scipy.signal import convolve2d as conv2


scan = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
                  ])
print(scan.shape)

psf = np.array([
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],#1
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],#2
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],#3
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],#4
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]#5
])

psf = psf/(np.sum(psf))
print(psf)

scan_conv = conv2(scan, psf, 'same')

deconvolved1, _ = restoration.unsupervised_wiener(scan_conv, psf, max_num_iter=10)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3, figsize=(8, 5),
                       sharex=True, sharey=True)

ax[0].imshow(scan, vmin=scan.min(), vmax=1)
ax[0].axis('off')
ax[0].set_title('Data')

ax[1].imshow(scan_conv)
ax[1].axis('off')
ax[1].set_title('Data_distorted')

ax[2].imshow(deconvolved1)
ax[2].axis('off')
ax[2].set_title('restoration1')

fig.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```